# add various "rel" attributes to fancybox galleries

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

i have a page with 4 fancybox (v.2) gallerys, and when i click trough the first gallery he circles through ALL galleries on the page, that's bad. so i want to give each gallery a different "rel" attribute (rel="gallery1", rel="gallery2", rel="gallery3" ...). so i need to count these gallerys and give them the number. my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        padding : 0,
        loop : false
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each gallery is in a `<div class="post">` like:

```
<!-- first gallery -->
<div class="post">
    <a class="fancybox">...</a>
    <a class="fancybox">...</a>
</div>

<!-- second gallery -->
<div class="post">
    <a class="fancybox">...</a>
    <a class="fancybox">...</a>
</div>
```

You simply need to use [`.each( function(index, element) )`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop over the `.post` elements. Use each `.post` index to build the gallery identifier, and use each `.post` element as a [jQuery selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) when selecting your `.fancybox` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".post").each(function(idx, elm) {
        $(".fancybox", elm)
            .attr('rel', 'gallery' + idx)
            .fancybox({
                // ...
            });
    });
});
...
```

`$(".fancybox", elm)` tells jQuery to look for elements with the `fancybox` class, but only match elements that are descendants of `elm` (here, the current `.post` element for the `.each` loop).

Depending on how fancybox works, you might be able to move the `.fancybox()` call outside of the `each`:

```
$(".post").each(function(idx, elm) {
    // assign `rel` values as above...
});

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // ...
});
```

Comment: this gives every .fancybox link the count, but i need to give all .fancybox links in EACH gallery the same count (gallery1: rel="gallery0, gallery2: rel="gallery1 ...).

Comment: @herrfischer I see. How do you determine which gallery a given link belongs to? If I look at any `.fancybox` element on your page, how could I tell which gallery it belongs to? I don't know fancybox very well. You can edit your question to include relevant HTML if necessary.

Comment: each gallery is in a DIV called "post". so i have to count the "post" DIVs (in this case 4 but it's dynamic) and give all .fancybox links inside the same rel attribute ...

Comment: @herrfischer Edited my answer to use `.each` over the `.post` elements.